# how to deal with different data type between R and sqlite in a simple way?

Tags: r, sqlite

data is a data.frame,there is a column `tdate`  whose type is character,now i want write the data into sqlite,

```
require(RSQLite)
dbWriteTable(con2, name="quote",value=data,row.names=FALSE,append=TRUE)
```

there is a still problem ,tdata is date type in sqlite,after i write the data into sqlite  database ,i'll   change the field `tdata` in table quote  into data type,is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: Did the `quote` table already exist with the wrong schema? Can you drop the table, recreate it with the right scheme and then `dbWriteTable` again? Or is there other data in the table you don't want to lose?

Comment: In general, it is fiddly to change the type of a sqlite column after the event, as you can [see here](http://lenss.nl/2009/07/change-columns-data-type-in-sqlite/)

Comment: in first ,require(RSQLite)    
drv <- dbDriver("SQLite")
condb<- dbConnect(drv, "profile.sqlite")
tablestr<-'create table quote  ("date" DATE);at last dbWriteTable(con2, name="quote",value=data,row.names=FALSE,append=TRUE)
dbGetQuery(condb, tablestr)

Comment: Note that SQLite doesn't actually have a Date type, just [Date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) that operate on strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
dbWriteTable(con2, name="quote",
   value=transform(data, date=format(date, "%Y-%m-%d")),
   row.names=FALSE,append=TRUE)
```

If your data is a character string not a date, then the `format` command is not necessary, noting that SQLite has no date format: dates are stored as strings in the YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: the date format is already  "%Y-%m-%d",but the data type is text,character still.

Comment: There is no DATE data type in SQLite